# Can someone please explain to me like I'm 5 years old the error " static reference to the non-static method "

Tags: java, static-methods

This error haunts me:

```
cannot make a static reference to the non-static method XYZ from the type ABC
```

My eyes just glaze over . I realize this question was asked before, but I want the 5-year old treatment.  It's just not making sense..

I'm running a class, I have code in the `public static void main` , then I make a function outside it.

Comment: A 5 year old would understand that you `cannot make a static reference to the non-static method XYZ from the type ABC` and change their code accordingly. Look up what an instance is.

Comment: It would help if you explained which parts of the existing explanations are unclear

Comment: @RichardTingle - Yeah I know. OK will do , thank you

Comment: You need at least one `new` before your code will work.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Thanks, yes I'm starting to understand this now!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you try to call in main does not have the static keyword.  Add it and the compiler won't complain.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        bar();
    }

    public static void bar() {
        System.out.println("compiler won't complain");
    }
}
```

That doesn't mean it's the right thing to do.

Static methods and members are associated with *classes*; non-static methods and members are associated with *instances*.  Make sure you understand the difference.  It'll be hard to do object-oriented coding if you don't.

If it's a non-static method, here's what you'd need to do:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.bar();  // Associated with the new Foo instance named foo.
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("compiler won't complain");
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it's the right one.

Comment: You're damn right it will reoccur. Duffymo has showed you a solution that is really just a band-aid while learning java. Very soon you will have to get out of main and use non-static methods.

Comment: This is clicking now , the concept of classes and instances. Thank you very much Sir

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to class members and instance members.  Please read this document for more details about why class members can't directly reference instance members.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: And, most 5 years old I know like bicycles :)

Comment: this is more comment-y but ok

Answer (score 1):

Java has "static" and "instance" methods.  A "static" method has `static` in its definition (such as the way you always say `static` for your `main` method.  An "instance" method does not have the word `static` in its definition.

A static method can be called from any environment, using `ClassName.staticMethodName(parms)`.  An instance method can only be invoked using a reference to an object of the method's class.  Ie, you must use `objectReference.instanceMethodName(parms)`, where `objectReference` references an object of the method's class.  (The `objectReference` is implied if calling from inside another instance method of the class.)

Answer (score 1):

If your function you create next to the `main` function is not static, then you can't call it from the `main` method, which is static.
That's because you're not creating any instance of the class that contains both of the functions. A method that is not static (thus, an instance method) needs inherently an instance of that class in order to be called.

Let's say you have the following example:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    }

    public void doSomething(){
    }
}
```

if you want to call the `doSomething()` method from the `main` method, it has to look like

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    new Test().doSomething();
}
```